# IE10 IE11 displays "This page can't be displayed" On large DOM - works in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an web application in MCV asp.net that needs to work in IE. Loading the application with data for some customers we get the "The page can not displayed" using IE10 and IE11.

More details are

- It works in Firefox.
- The error is only there for large pages = larger DOM
- An exampel of a large page is a body of 4.6MB measured by Fiddler
- For small pages there are no problems
- The error page apears instantly when loading a customer

We have tried the following, but with no luck:

- Removing stepwise elements from a big page and at some point it will start working, since it just removing sets of the same elements, nothing is being removed that could couse the problem  - maybe its something with the size of the http-response?
- Changed some IE settings
- Stripping away all Jquery and CSS, to see if it was some DOM traversal issues
- Tjekking the http-response to look for any bugs - non found
- Google around seams that IE will show this page in some situations, but not found anything to fix this problem, where the application works on some pages but not on others.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Tested removing the AntiForeryTokens, from the partial views then it loads fine. It seams to be somewhere in the region of 200 AntiForgeryTokens that is the limit for IE.

Comment: also see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072264/mvc-antiforgerytoken-limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to why it does not work in IE is that you can not have more then about 200 AntiForgeryTokens, above that will make IE not load the page.

The quick solution: reduce the number of AntiForgeryTokens, we could do it by not having a delete form per element.